# How to add 'controls' attribute to 'amp-carousel' when using AMP plugin?

Tags: amp-html

I want to keep the buttons on the `amp-carousel` gallery always visible and that needs the `controls` attribute. Since I am using AMP official plugin, I don't know to add this attribute to the `amp-carousel` output since the plugin controls the output of that.

Answer (score 2):

after some time trying to do the same as you asked i found a way to solve this question. hope that help you.

in your wordpress project on folder wp-content -> theme ->  has file called `functions.php`.

you must hook the action `amp_content_sanitizers` using the function `add_filter` and 
implement your own function. but first you need create a new class that extends from `AMP_Base_Sanitizer` and override the method `sanitize()` like:

add a new file

file name ex: Custom_AMP_Carousel_Injection_Sanitizer.php

located at folder 'classes' inside you theme folder.

```
<?php

require_once( AMP__DIR__ . '/includes/sanitizers/class-amp-base-sanitizer.php' );

class Custom_AMP_Carousel_Injection_Sanitizer extends AMP_Base_Sanitizer {
    public function sanitize() {
        $ampCarouselNodeList = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName('amp-carousel');
        foreach($ampCarouselNodeList as $node){
            $node->setAttribute('controls', '');
        }
    }
}
```

in `functions.php` from your theme folder:

```
add_filter( 'amp_content_sanitizers', 'custom_amp_add_carousel_sanitizer', 10, 2 );
function custom_amp_add_carousel_sanitizer( $sanitizer_classes, $post ) {
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/custom_amp_carousel_injection_sanitizer.php' );
    $sanitizer_classes['Custom_AMP_Carousel_Injection_Sanitizer'] = array();
    return $sanitizer_classes;
}
```

this also can help you:

https://amp-wp.org/documentation/how-the-plugin-works/amp-content-rendering-in-wordpress/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Answer (score 0):

The way to add `controls` attribute in `amp-carousel` was defined in the documentation itself.

As described:

`controls` - Permanently displays left and right arrows for the user to navigate carousel items on mobile devices.

Here is an example of how it is implemented, example taken from the [documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-carousel?format=websites#attributes).

> ```
> <amp-carousel type="slides"
>   width="450"
>   height="300"
>   controls
>   loop
>   autoplay
>   delay="3000"
>   data-next-button-aria-label="Go to next slide"
>   data-previous-button-aria-label="Go to previous slide">
>   <amp-img src="images/image1.jpg"
>     width="450"
>     height="300"></amp-img>
>   <amp-img src="images/image2.jpg"
>     width="450"
>     height="300"></amp-img>
>   <amp-img src="images/image3.jpg"
>     width="450"
>     height="300"></amp-img>
> </amp-carousel>
> ```

Comment: No, since the AMP plugin controls the output of amp-carousel, I cannot modify it. It's not like I am manually adding a gallery, AMP is converting the **default WordPress gallery** to `amp-carousel`. So, I am hoping if there is any way to inject the `controls` attribute via any custom code.